# Qt websocket, connect to server

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

I'm trying to connect to "wss://api.huobi.pro/ws". 
After connecting I have to subscribe to the channel with message "{"id":"wanbtc","sub":"market.wanbtc.depth.step0"}"

```
    auto ws = new WebSocketSync;
    ws->setIs_display_scan_speed(new bool(false));

    QJsonObject json;
    json["sub"] = "market.wanbtc.depth.step0";
    json["id"] = "wanbtc";

    ws->set_url("wss://api.huobi.pro/ws");
    ws->set_register_message(QJsonDocument(json).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

    ws->open();
```

Code result:

```
[Websocket] Current soket state: QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState
[Websocket] Current soket state: QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState
[Websocket] Connected to server "wss://api.huobi.pro/ws"
[Websocket] Send message to server "{\"id\":\"wanbtc\",\"sub\":\"market.wanbtc.depth.step0\"}"
```

But after the socket does not send any data

Similar code works on node.js

```
const moment = require('moment');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const pako = require('pako');

const WS_URL = 'wss://api.huobi.pro/ws';


var orderbook = {};

exports.OrderBook = orderbook;

function handle(data) {
    console.log('received', data.ch, 'data.ts', data.ts, 'crawler.ts', moment().format('x'));
    let symbol = data.ch.split('.')[1];
    let channel = data.ch.split('.')[2];
    switch (channel) {
        case 'depth':
            orderbook[symbol] = data.tick;
            //console.log(data.tick);
            break;
    }
}

function subscribe(ws) {
    var symbols = ['wanbtc'];

    for (let symbol of symbols) {
        var message = JSON.stringify({
            "sub": `market.${symbol}.depth.step0`,
            "id": `${symbol}`
        });
        console.log('send to ws ' + message);
        ws.send(message);
    }

}

function init() {

    var ws = new WebSocket(WS_URL);
    ws.on('open', () => {
        console.log('connect to ' + WS_URL);
        subscribe(ws);
    });
    ws.on('message', (data) => {
        let text = pako.inflate(data, {
            to: 'string'
        });
        let msg = JSON.parse(text);
        if (msg.tick) {
            // console.log(msg);
            handle(msg);
        }

    });
}

init();
```

What could be the reason? working on node.js, not working on Qt. Need to find a replacement for QWebsocket?

**Edit 1:**
WebSocketSync.cpp

```
WebSocketSync::WebSocketSync()
{
    connect(&m_socket, &QWebSocket::connected, this, [=]{

        qDebug() << "[Websocket] Connected to server" << m_socket.request().url().toString();

        if (m_is_need_to_register_channel) {

            qDebug() << "[Websocket] Send message to server" << m_register_message;
            m_socket.sendTextMessage(m_register_message);
        }

    });

    connect(&m_socket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived, this, [=](const QString & message) {
        qDebug() << message;
    });

}

void WebSocketSync::set_url(const QString &url)
{
//    qDebug() << "[Websocket] Server url setted:" << url;

    m_url.setUrl(url);
}

void WebSocketSync::set_register_message(const QString &url)
{
//    qDebug() << "[Websocket] Register message setted:" << url;

    m_is_need_to_register_channel = true;
    m_register_message = url;
}

void WebSocketSync::open()
{
//    qDebug() << "[Websocket] Open url:" << m_url;

    m_socket.open(m_url);
}
```

Comment: There is no `WebSocketSync` class in Qt. It seems you use some other lib or your example is incomplete.

Comment: @KonstantinT. WebSocketSync is my wrapper over the QWebsocket class. I added code

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the server sent out binary data. I need to use `QWebSocket::binaryMessageReceived` for this connection.
Now i need to figure out how to handle binary data (\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00)